# Make: Error on libowfat

Tags: linux, makefile, debian

Everytime I try to use the make command on libowfat (A program) it seems to error.

Output:
root@vps:~/libowfat# make: gcc: Command not found
-bash: make:: command not found

Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't installed a compiler or make program on your system.  You don't say what kind of system you're using but you do have a `debian` tag; if you're using a Debian or Ubuntu system, you should try running (as root):

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Also, just a note: you should never, ever be building things while logged in as root.  It's easy for a stray bad command in a makefile or whatever to completely trash your system.

Comment: Yes! That seems to have fixed the first error but now at the next command I got a new error: (/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opentracker] Error 1). And thanks for the root tip. I will make sure to fix it. If the current software damages the system its fine since its just a fresh installed template. And yes I indeed use Debian 6. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: `-lz` is the zlib library.  You should use `apt-get install zlib1g-dev` to get the development package for that library.  I'm not sure your system uses that exact package name, but you want to look for `zlib*-dev` for some value of `*`.